# Make 1 histogram from 4 columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset (d) with 7 columns where the last 4 columns are age (e1, e2, e3, e4). I would like to make a histogram for all values of age. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for a ggplot2 solution?

Comment: Yes, looking for a ggplot2, but not sure how to go about it

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample data (`dput(your_data[1:5, c("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4")])` would be a great way to share a copy/pasteable sample), and let us know what you tried. It might help too if you explain what you're looking for - a bar plot showing counts of discrete ages, or a histogram showing density of binned ages? And is there any meaning to a "row" that needs to be preserved in the plot?

Answer (score 1):

To get you started: Here is a ggplot2-solution on simulated data. First, we simulate your dataset `d`:

```r
n = 10
a = rep(NA,n)
b = rep(NA,n)
c = rep(NA,n)
e1 = sample.int(100,n)
e2 = sample.int(100,n)
e3 = sample.int(100,n)
e4 = sample.int(100,n)
d = data.frame(a,b,c,e1,e2,e3,e4)
```

Second, we extract your ages:

```r
ages = data.frame(value = unlist(d[c("e1","e2","e3","e4")]))
```

Third, we plot the histogram (of frequencies):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ages, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10)
```